# How to use VueCompositionAPI with Vue 3?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, vuejs3

I updated all the packages in my project. And upgrade vue 3.
After the done with updates there is a problem in my code.
I cannot use `Vue.use(VueCompositionAPI);`
In the old version of the project I call it from import VueCompositionAPI from '@vue/composition-api';
but this package is not compatible with due 3 anymore so I cannot call it.
What shouldd I do?

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "front",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Frontend",
  "main": ".eslintrc.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "test:e2e": "vue-cli-service test:e2e",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
  },
  "keywords": [
    "fdm"
  ],
  "author": "etc",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^3.0.1",
    "@jsonforms/core": "^2.5.2",
    "@jsonforms/vue": "^2.5.2",
    "@jsonforms/vue-vanilla": "^2.5.2",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-nightwatch": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-mocha": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb": "^6.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.2",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.22.0",
    "chai": "^4.3.6",
    "chromedriver": "^103.0.0",
    "core-js": "^3.23.4",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.2.0",
    "geckodriver": "^3.0.2",
    "json-schema-ref-parser": "^9.0.9",
    "jsonpath": "^1.1.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "npm": "^8.13.2",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.7.2",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
    "vue": "^3.2.37",
    "vue-axios": "^3.4.1",
    "vue-bootstrap4-table": "^1.1.11",
    "vue-router": "^4.1.1",
    "vue-sorted-table": "^1.3.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.4",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.24.3",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.18.2",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0"
  }
}
```

my main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { BootstrapVue } from 'bootstrap-vue';
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import SortedTablePlugin from 'vue-sorted-table';
import {
  faSpinner, faSortUp, faSortDown, faSort, faFilter, faCheck, faTimesCircle, faUser, faPause,
  faTrash,
} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { FontAwesomeIcon, FontAwesomeLayers } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome';
import App from './App.vue';
import './registerServiceWorker';
import router from './router';
import store from './store';


Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.use(VueCompositionAPI);
// Install BootstrapVue
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
Vue.use(SortedTablePlugin);

library.add(
  faSpinner,
);

Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon);
Vue.component('font-awesome-layers', FontAwesomeLayers);

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

Comment: In no way. It shouldn't be used with Vue 3

Comment: Vue 3 introduced composition api, that package just backports them to make them compatible with vue 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look, vue 2 is build on the options API.
Vue 3 is build on composition API.

In order to use composition API in your Vue 2 app, you needed the @vue/composition-api package to run it.

What you did is: You upgraded to 3 (wich is by default composition API) and try to use the @vue/composition-api wich is only made for vue 2 in order to use the composition API. But vue 3 is by default composition API. I hope you get me here.

Also, since 2.7 you dont even need this package anymore

Also there is a note:

> When you migrate to Vue 3, just replacing @vue/composition-api to vue
> and your code should just work.

In vue 2.x you did:

```
const { ref, reactive } = VueCompositionAPI
```

In vue 3.x you do:

```
import { ref, reactive } from "vue"
```

or:

```
const { ref, reactive } = Vue;
```